# Entering a string with new line characters into excel using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a string str.

```
$str="abcd_1
      abcd_2
      abcd_3"
```

First in the for-loop I am concatenating the string and making a full string of Id's with a carriage return+newline character.
And on splitting I am using just the new line character.
I am getting a space in front in the data which is entered from the second cell.

```
for($intRow = $trow ; $intRow -le $maxRow ; $intRow++){

                            $codeName = $currentCode
                            $fin = $codeName + "_" + $i + "`r`n"
                            $finCode=$finCode+$fin


                            $i= $i + 1
                         }



                         $currentSheet.Cells.Item($fRow,$currentCol).Value2  = $finCode



                         $clipboardData = $finCode.Split("`n").TrimStart()
                         $newClipboardData = $clipboardData.Where({$_.TrimStart() -ne ""}).ForEach({$_.TrimStart()})
                         [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetText($newClipboardData)



                         $currentSheet.Cells.Item($fRow,$currentCol).Select() | Out-Null
                         $currentSheet.Paste() | Out-Null
```

Comment: You have to increase the row count and use `for each` statement to iterate through each single value in the string by splitting them using `ToString().Split()` method.

Comment: I don't want to use a loop as it takes a lot of time . Just like u copy this string and paste it in excel then you will have 3 cells occupied. In my case all the content is getting populated in one cell only. So i want a command in which all the content is populated in all the 3 cells of the excel rather only in one cell.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be more clear and precise. This example shows how to split the string by new line character. Just increase the `$intRow` every time to write in next row:

```
ForEach($strValue In $str.Split("`n"))
{
    $currentSheet.Cells.Item($intRow,$currentCol).Value2  = $strValue
    $intRow++
}
```

New Code:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetText($str.Split("`n"))
$currentSheet.Cells.Item($intRow,$currentCol).Select() | Out-Null
$currentSheet.Paste() | Out-Null
```

Comment: bro I don't want to use this in for-loop as this method takes a lot of time. Rather i will make it a string with new line character and then I need to click on the excel and then paste it over there.So all the values get pasted in one turn only so I don't have to maintain a connection between the powershell and the excel again and again.

Comment: In that case you can first put the data in clipboard and then paste it in excel. It will take care of splitting the data in multiple cells based on new line. See the new code.

Comment: I have edited the code above which I used yours. I have used " 'r'n" instead of " 'n " . I am getting the first record correct but in the second record of the excel I am getting a space first and then the record gets inserted. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate spaces using trim. But splitting using `'r'n` is not giving me correct data. It is returning a single line.:

```
$clipboardData = $str.Split("`n").TrimStart()
$newClipboardData = $clipboardData.Where({$_.TrimStart() -ne ""}).ForEach({$_.TrimStart()})
[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetText($newClipboardData)
```

When I checked the contents of the values it does not have any leading spaces but it shows a single space when pasted in excel.

```
$newClipboardData | %{ "-$_-" }
-Some Text-
-Some text With spaces  -
-Some text again-
```

Comment: I have made changes in the code above please see that............ after using your changes I am still getting that one space in front of the element in the cell.

Comment: I am getting error from the second element in the cell of the excel and after that all the cells are done with a space in the front.

Comment: I have made the changes suggested by you and updated above in the question. Please have a look. Its still giving that space from the second row.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how those spaces are getting appended. As you can see, the sample output I put above using `$newClipboardData | %{ "-$_-" }` does not have the spaces in output. I have no clue.